# Barman geo-redundancy configuration error

Tags: postgresql, barman

I trying to config the geo-redundancy on my barman setup, but i get an error when i try to copy from primary to secundary backup, my configuration is:

**SERVER 1**

- Ubuntu 18 on Virtual Box
- Postgres 12
- 192.168.0.103
- /etc/barman.conf

```
backup_method = rsync
archiver = on
compression = gzip
reuse_backup = link
backup_options = concurrent_backup
parallel_jobs = 2
network_compression = true
basebackup_retry_times = 20
basebackup_retry_sleep = 120
```

- /etc/barman.d/comauto_20200921_95

```
[comauto_20200921_95]
description =  "Comauto Local Postgres 9.5 - 21/09/2020"
conninfo = host=192.168.0.102 user=barman dbname=postgres
ssh_command = ssh postgres@192.168.0.102
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 WEEKS
backup_options = exclusive_backup
```

**SERVER 2**

- Ubuntu 18 on Virtual Box
- Postgres 9.5
- ifconfig = 192.168.0.102
- /etc/barman.conf

```
backup_method = rsync
archiver = on
compression = gzip
reuse_backup = link
backup_options = concurrent_backup
parallel_jobs = 2
network_compression = true
basebackup_retry_times = 20
basebackup_retry_sleep = 120
; the only difference
primary_ssh_command = barman@192.168.0.103
```

- /etc/barman.d/comauto_20200921_95

```
[comauto_20200921_95]
description =  "Comauto Local Postgres 9.5 - 21/09/2020"
conninfo = host=192.168.0.102 user=barman dbname=postgres
ssh_command = ssh postgres@192.168.0.102
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 WEEKS
backup_options = exclusive_backup
```

**On server 1:**

```sh
sudo su barman
ssh barman@192.168.0.102 -C true
 # OK
barman check comauto_20200921_95
 # All OK
barman backup comauto_20200921_95
 # OK
barman list-backup comauto_20200921_95
 # comauto_20200921_95 20201111T172643 - Wed Nov 11 17:26:50 2020 - Size: 6.2 GiB - WAL Size: 0 B
 # comauto_20200921_95 20201111T114656 - Wed Nov 11 11:47:08 2020 - Size: 6.2 GiB - WAL Size: 79.9 KiB
 # comauto_20200921_95 20201111T112906 - Wed Nov 11 11:33:10 2020 - Size: 6.2 GiB - WAL Size: 96.4 KiB
```

**The error happens here**

**On server 2:**

```sh
sudo su barman
ssh barman@192.168.0.103 -C true
 # OK
barman check comauto_20200921_95
 # WAL archive: FAILED
 # ssh: FAILED (Connection failed using 'barman@192.168.0.103 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' return code 127)
barman cron
 # ERROR: Failed to retrieve the primary node status: sync-info execution on remote primary server comauto_20200921_95 failed: /bin/sh: 1: barman@192.168.0.103: not found
barman list-backup comauto_20200921_95
 #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious issue is that `primary_ssh_command` is missing the actual `ssh`; it should presumably be:

```
; the only difference
primary_ssh_command = ssh barman@192.168.0.103
```

See example in the documentation here: https://docs.pgbarman.org/#configuration-1